# Access and edit private field value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
FieldInfo gamegui = admingui.GetType().GetField("gamemode", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)



        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
        {
            foreach (Client client4 in UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<Client>())
            {
            admingui.gamemode = 5;
            gamegui = 5;
            }
        }
```

it's private int AdminGUI.gamemode , i need some help fixing these issues
Details:
i try to edit AdminGUI.gamemode
to change game mode selection
how can i bind that private int? ... and edit it ...

Comment: Can't you make it public?

Comment: i can't make it public

Comment: Have a look at properties.

Comment: how to change that private int AdminGUI.gamemode (i don't know what you mean "Have a look at properties"

Comment: Why can't you make it public? If it's not "your" code, what is private is supposed to represent implementation details, not to be changed by someone else. So, either a SetGameMode(...) method or a GameMode property encapsulating the private field are provided by the class implementer, or I would dare to say that you shouldn't be changing directly the value at all.

Comment: If it's not meant to be public then you probably shouldn't change it, are you sure it's even safe to do? Using reflection you *might* be able to do it but it might not be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a value with the `FieldInfo` Object

```
gamegui.SetValue(admingui, 5);
```